# vim: how to remove spaces between the cursor and the code?

Tags: vim

I have this lines

```
     aaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```

If I have the cursor in the line with a's at the first column, how can i move the group of a's in the same position as the rest of the lines?

Comment: If the indentation rules are set up properly for your language: `=` `=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three (generalized) ways to accomplish your goal:

1. To manually adjust indentation to the left, you can use <kbd><</kbd><kbd><</kbd> to shift left once (repeat with <kbd>.</kbd> to acheive desired level of indentation).
2. If you're already in insert mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> will shift the current line to the left.
3. Auto-indent using <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

However, given your initial description of being at column 1, and wanting the `a`'s to be in line with the others, I would probably just use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to delete until the first a.

**edit:** as Tim Pote notes, <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> is a more efficient way to delete white space to the first character. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish from your description, though (i.e. are you merely trying to delete white space, or all characters until the `a`'s begin?)

Answer (score 2):

If you're already at the first column, I would use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> for delete word.  That will delete all the whitespace between your current column and a word.

All of the other alternatives depend on shifting indentation, which may or may not delete all the whitespace in one go, depending on your settings.  Either that you you've got to use the letter-specific <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, which is also more keystrokes.