# vim: how to delete spaces till the first character?

Tags: vim

I have a line like this:

```
      foobar
```

as you can see there are many spaces between the first column and 'foobar'. If I have the cursor in the first column, is there any key binding to remove the spaces till 'foobar'?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/10363730/836738

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

Will delete all the whitespace if you're on the first column.

Answer (score 4):

```
dtf
```

Delete Till F

<del>There is no other easy command. You could use a regex, but that'd be more painful to write.</del>

My bad, @Mat's answer is even better (`dw`).

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is

```
dw
```

...which performs [d]elete [w]ord. If you want to remove all whitespace in the whole document before all occurences of "foobar":

```
:%s/^\s*foobar/foobar/
```

Answer (score 1):

use `:%s/\s\+$//e`

\s stands for space and tab + find one or more occurence

You can find more details in [Remove unwanted spaces](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:
Go to the line, and `:s/^  *//g`

Way 2:
Go to the first blank space of that line and press `dw`

Comment: Way 3: Go to the first word and press `d0`